# Программа выполняется только один раз

Tags: python

Пожалуйста подскажите, почему эта программа выполняется, только один раз?(Не обращайте внимание на отвлекающие обьекты)

```
import vk_api, pickle, requests, time, datetime, threading
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
from lxml import etree as et

def Gettime():
    Time = datetime.datetime.now().time()
    Time = str(Time)
    Time = Time[0:5]
    return Time


def ReminderTime(t0):
    t1 = int(Gettime()[0:2] + Gettime()[3:5])
    if (t1-t0) >= 1:
        print('fjlfd')
        for i in Reminder:
            if [i,2] == getTime():
                write_msg(event.user_id, 'Напоминаю ' + Reminder[i,3])
        t0 = t1

def mainMy():
    print('main')

t0 = int(Gettime()[0:2] + Gettime()[3:5])

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=ReminderTime(t0))
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=mainMy)

thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

Comment: а сколько раз он должен выполняться? сюда по коду так и должно быть.

Comment: Спасибо. Уже разобрался, по моей задумке, он должен был не останавливаться  :)